# Why CTAS statement is so fast in Azure SQL DW?

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-data-warehouse

I have noticed that [Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas) in SQL Data Warehouse statements  are extremely fast compared to Select into statement.

I want to know what magic microsoft did to make it so fast?

Answer (score -1):

The magic is: Polybase with minimal transaction loging

Comment: Please elaborate.